# CE1.9 - Compatibility of MariaDB 10.1 (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: database

I'm developing locally on Arch Linux, and just began setting up my local dev environment. I installed mysql using `pacman -S mysql` which according to the [AUR package details](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mysql/) lists it as *mysql 5.7.17*. I know from previous sites, that I don't have any issues running a CE1.9 site in MySQL 5.7, but Arch Linux does not give me the option to choose Oracle MySQL as the provider when I initially install it (only `mariadb` or `percona-server`).

I've already received a compatibility warning when I opened MySQL Workbench about MariaDB (although I just feel that this is just merely a warning due to not finding an Oracle MySQL database), and just wonder if I may run into any foreseeable issues?

So I'm a bit confused as the Package Details page states:

> Conflicts:    mariadb
>   Provides: mariadb=5.7.17

Are any of you running any CE1.9 sites with MariaDB 10.1 without any issues?

Many thanks!